# What makes something "worthy of being honored"?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah, bitul-batel-null

When a piece of meat is in a mixture that should nullify it, we don't consider it nullified if it is ראוי להתכבד, or "worthy of being honored", something you would serve to a guest. Is there some kind of objective measure for this, or is it dependent on the time and place, or even the dish or the guest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is subject to current societal standards.

Aruch HaShulchan ([YD 101:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.101.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> כבר נתבאר דחה"ל תלוי לפי המקום ולפי הזמן והכל לפי ראות עיני המורה
>
> It has already been explained that *chaticha hare'uya lehischabed*
>   depends on the place and the time, and it all goes according to the
>   way it appears before the [particular] rabbi.

An important aside, the Aruch Hashulchan seems to suggest that a small piece of meat that is only ראויה להתכבד when served with more pieces of meat is excluded from the category of חה"ל. (AhS [ibid. 27](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.101.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))